# xpath query question

Tags: iphone, xml, xpath

below is my xml document and right now my query is: `/description/*/text()`, I can get all the text except that the text inside the `<strong> lunch </strong>` which "lunch" doesn't display.

This is probably a simple fix but I just couldn't get it correct.

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
<p>
     Envie is a brand new Bar Lounge that offers a modern-design space opening onto Wyndham Street, where on busy nights the crowd spills out onto the street...
</p>
<p>
     If you are in for a <strong>lunch</strong>, the Twangoo voucher will offer you two delicious Lunches &ndash; perfect for that lunch meeting, a casual date or just a get together with friends in a relaxed and modern atmosphere.
</p> ]]>
</description>
```

Comment: You XML contains `CDATA`? You need to parse XML inside `CDATA`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
/description//text()
```

Right now you are selecting every text only for all the child nodes of description.

If you use `//text()` instead; you are selecting every text for all nodes that are descendant of the current node (description).

Comment: It was a pleasure. If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as Solved. It saves some time to many people.

Answer (score 0):

Your query /description/*/text() selects the text node children of the element children of the description element. But the description element has no element children. It would have, except that the CDATA is telling the parser not to treat the `<p>...</p>` content as markup, but as plain text. I don't know why the XML is wrapping this stuff in CDATA, but it makes it much harder to process it or query it.